# What is the optimal economy layout for a no rush game in Age of Empires 3?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

I always have trouble organizing my settlers in a no rush game to gather resources. So let me make a scenario. Let's say I'm playing as the french who have a max villager pop of 70, how many should I task on each resource (Assuming I have the max settler pop) How many on Food, Wood, and Gold?

Same thing for the Portugese which have a 99 pop?

Answer (score 1):

I find this is really situational.  In the early game (just starting; long before reaching the settler cap [which I rarely ever do]) I prioritize food.  Everyone on food except 1 for wood, and 1 for coin.  I tend to maintain about a 3:1:1 ratio for a while until I've advance a bit, have an army, or are experiencing shortages.

What you prioritize from then on really depends.  The map, the game so far, and your economy's early success are all factors.  Ocean map? You're gonna need lots of wood for a navy.  Couldn't find much coin? You might want to invest in some whalers.  Got rushed early on*? You're gonna need more settlers on the resources required for whatever troops you decide to build to defend (which, again, is situational, depending on what you were attacked with).

Around reaching 50-60 settlers I find I soon have ample resources to field an army that brings me to my population limit.  At that point, there's not much to do but attack.

I would advise a bare minimum of 10 settlers per resource, but be careful you don't build *too many* settlers, as an extra 10000 of everything doesn't help you when your 100 troops get defeated by the 150 enemy troops, and your buildings are destroyed before you can make more.

<sup>*In your specific case, you said this won't happen, but I'm trying to cover the bases.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have a good economy,try putting 20 villagers per resource minimum. (If you really want to build up a shock economy,put either 30 per resource,or 40 per food and coins and 15 per wood,assuming that you have the 99 limit). At countries with smaller villager build limits,but with better villagers,try the first variant. Also,try using Cree Courier de Bois,if you have Cree as natives. When playing as germans,also use Settler Wagons at coins and food,10 each.